# SUM Function Does Not Add Correctly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table from which I calculate the sum of values in a particular column. The table is:

```
PayTable

Amount       GRPS        
65,025.00    355
-2,500.00    355
7,014.40     355
725.62       355
241.67       355
1,209.57     355
241.87       355
241.87       355
```

The query is:

```
SELECT   GRPS,SUM(Amount) AS AMT into AmtTab FROM PayTable GROUP BY  GRPS
```

This should give me a sum of 72200, however it returns 72199.999999999985 instead. However, it only does this for the group 355, for other groups, the calculation is correct

Comment: What is datatype of  `Amount`? is it `float` or `decimal`?

Comment: What datatype is Amount? I have a feeling it is float?

Comment: Try `sum(cast (amount as decimal (10,2)))` and see if that returns what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your datatype. But see the following examples of returned values. In MSSQL 2012 your situation seems to correspond to the datatype REAL. While **MONEY, FLOAT, DECIMAL, DOUBLE PRECISION** return 72200.00 **REAL** returns 72199.9998321533. See below:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempso (Amount money, GRPS int);

INSERT INTO #tempso(Amount, GRPS) VALUES
('65025.00',355),
('-2500.00',355),
('7014.40',355),
('725.62',355),
('241.67',355),
('1209.57',355),
('241.87',355),
('241.87',355)

SELECT GRPS,SUM(Amount) AS AMT FROM #tempso GROUP BY  GRPS

ALTER TABLE #tempso ALTER COLUMN Amount float
SELECT GRPS,SUM(Amount) AS AMT FROM #tempso GROUP BY  GRPS

ALTER TABLE #tempso ALTER COLUMN Amount decimal(10,2)
SELECT GRPS,SUM(Amount) AS AMT FROM #tempso GROUP BY  GRPS

ALTER TABLE #tempso ALTER COLUMN Amount DOUBLE PRECISION
SELECT GRPS,SUM(Amount) AS AMT FROM #tempso GROUP BY  GRPS

        --------------- 
RETURNS:|355 72200.00 |
        ---------------

ALTER TABLE #tempso ALTER COLUMN Amount REAL
SELECT GRPS,SUM(Amount) AS AMT FROM #tempso GROUP BY  GRPS

        ----------------------  
RETURNS:|355 72199.9998321533 |
        ----------------------

DROP TABLE #tempso
```

You may want to change the column datatype (if it is not a desired type, perhaps it was set by mistake from the dropdown menu of SQL Studio, etc.) or CAST the value as one of the above datatypes which will return desired **72200.00**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Andy Korneyev...`sum(cast (amount as decimal (10,2)))` fixed the problem!